# replaceAll, regex and HashMap return me a NullPointerException

Tags: java, regex, hashmap

I have the following code:

```
HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
hm.put("title", "testTitle");
hm.put("year", "testYear");

String s = "<title> - <year>";

String result = s.replaceAll("<([^>]*)>", hm.get("$1"));
```

The problem is when I execute it, it returns me this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.String.replaceAll(Unknown Source)

I don't understand why, because when executed alone, **hm.get("title")** does work, so why with replaceAll it is not?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following line:

```
String result = s.replaceAll("<([^>]*)>", hm.get("$1"));
```

1. First, `hm.get("$1")` gets executed (and returns `null` since presumably there's no entry in `hm` with the key equal to `"$1"`).
2. Second, `s.replaceAll("<([^>]*)>", null)` is called and triggers the NPE.

One way to do what you're trying to do is to use a [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) and a loop.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, this seems to be the best way to do it!

Answer (score 1):

Recheck your syntax. Read up on "evaluation order".

```
hm.get("$1")
```

will look for a hash table entry with the key **exactly** "`$1`". Which doesn't exist, so you get back `null`. The regexp has at this point not yet been applied, and there is no statement that would substitute `$1` with the group.

The line

```
String result = s.replaceAll("<([^>]*)>", hm.get("$1"));
```

is equivalent to:

```
String nulLValue = hm.get("$1"); // Note: $1 is not substituted.
String result = s.replaceAll("<([^>]*)>", nullValue);
```

Have a look at the various Java examples involving `Pattern` and associated `Matcher`s.

Answer (score 1):

The following might not be perfect or optimal, and might fail in some corner cases, but it works with your example :

```
HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
hm.put("title", "testTitle");
hm.put("year", "testYear");

String s = "<title> - <year>";

Scanner scan = new Scanner(s);
scan.useDelimiter("<|>");
while (scan.hasNext()) {
    final String token = scan.next();
    final String value = hm.get(token);
    if (value != null) {
        s = s.replace("<" + token + ">", value);
    }
}

System.out.println(s);
```